# Object with fields that depend on another field

Tags: custom-field

I have an object that should be displayed like this:
[image]

I don't want to create repetitive fields D_A D_B D_C etc
is there a way I can create a picklist field with the values A,B,C
And when I create a new object fields will be automatically linked to A, B and C?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really need is a child object, check out the documentation [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm)

So create your child object and then create fields A, B & C on it.

Then D, E, F, G, H & I will be records of that child object.

So each record will have fields A, B & C on it.

You will also need a relationship field to relate the child object to the object you originally started working with.

Comment: So the parent has D E F ... fields. If the child object has A, B & C how am I going to fix that the A corresponds to D, or E or... ?

Comment: Added some more detail to my answer, let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: I fixed it by overriding the new page to look like this table. and each column is a record.